# How to select a processor/memory combination for overclocking?

Tags: memory, intel-core-i7, overclocking

I am looking to rebuild an older system of mine which is past it's prime.

I intend to keep many of the existing components (hard drives, GPU, case, fans, etc) but I do intend to replace the motherboard, memory and CPU.

**I understand a bit about overclocking a system, but I can't find a good reference on overclocking the newer i7 series of processors.** I'm also not sure about which motherboard would best support overclocking the i7 series. I was also considering overclocking the memory used with the build, but I haven't found much in that space either.

I've had good results with Asus models in the past - but that doesn't necessarily mean anything now.

**Any advice or resources about i7 overclocking, or particular builds would be helpful.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find a good reference on
>   overclocking the newer i7 series of
>   processors.

Here are some overclocking guides from reputable websites:

**MaximumPC:**

**[Ultimate Core i7 Overclocking Guide -- We Push Nehalem to its Limits](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/ultimate_core_i7_overclocking_guide_we_push_nehalem_its_limits)**

**Tom's Hardware:**

**[Editor's Corner: Overclocking Core i7](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/overclocking-core-i7,2063.html)**

**Bit-Tech.net:**

**[Overclocking Intel's Core i7 920](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/cpus/2008/11/06/overclocking-intel-core-i7-920/1)**

**XbitLabs:**

**[Intel Core i7-920 Overclocking Guide](http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/cpu/display/core-i7-920-overclocking.html)**

**AnandTech:**

**[Overclocking Core i7: A Tale of Two Retail Processors…](http://www.anandtech.com/cpuchipsets/intel/showdoc.aspx?i=3502)**

... and the nice folks at the **[Overclockers.com forum](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/)** gladly provide help and advice for anything overclocking.